# How to start command after reboot in Ubuntu? (Crontab and rc.local are not working)

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I need to run this command on Ubuntu after the reboot

```
FLASK_APP=/home/pi/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/examples/app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

I tried 'crontab' and 'rc.local', but none of them works. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this an app that should be always running on your system, or do you just want it to run once to do a specific task at boot time? Which version of Ubuntu are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by cron with @reboot directive

```
@reboot export FLASK_APP=/home/pi/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/examples/app.py
```